# How to override configurations of amCharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, amcharts

How could I override configurations of my chart in some other file (set gap)?
My configurations located at const, at confChart.js
P.S. I tried chartGraph(gap=100), but it didn't work(
Thanks for the answer)

```js
export const chartGraph = (name, type, gap}) => ({
    title: name,
    gapPeriod: gap,
    forceGap: true,
    connect: false,
    balloonText: '<b>[[title]]</b>',
    lineThickness: 1.5,
    type: 'smoothedLine',
});
```

Comment: You have a trailing `}` bracket. Is it `({name, type, gap})` or `(name, type, gap)` ?

Comment: ({name, type, gap})

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
export const chartGraph = (name, type, gap) => ({
       title: name,
       gapPeriod: gap,
       forceGap: true,
       connect: false,
       balloonText: '<b>[[title]]</b>',
       lineThickness: 1.5,
       type: type,
});
```

Without the }
and then if you want to override call in some other function:

```
chartGraph.gapPeriod = 100
```

In case it's not working please send more part of your code or explain better what it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`charGraph` just returns an `Object`. It accepts an `Object` as an argument. So to override the defaults which there aren't any, you do can do:

```
const myOptions = { name: 'example', type: 'example', gap: 'example' }
chartGraph(myOptions)
```

Your function is using [Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Comment: Don't work :(
I use function onClick:
test() {
        const myOptions = {  gap: 360000 }
        chartGraph(myOptions);
}

Comment: You'll need to update your question to include how you're calling the function.

Comment: I call function :
 test() {
 //place for the answer
}